# Link tags to tag info instead of related questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/what-is-best-temperature-sensor-for-an-array-of-sensors) a link to Wikipedia's I2C page was added. Personally I would like a link to [our own wiki](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/i2c/info) better. (The I2C wiki is one of the pages which *does* contain some information.)

Now I can link to it like I did here, or use the [i2c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i2c) tag, but that goes to a page with a list of questions tagged [i2c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i2c), not the info page. For the info page you have to click the "learn more..." link.

Can we make the info page the default when clicking on a tag link *in a text body*? I understand that a tag link when asking a question is useful to see (possibly) related questions, so for the tags under a question I would retain the link like it is now.

So, **feature request:** link to the wiki info page when using a tag link in a text body.

Comment: I think the first sentence here detracts from your question, it is completely tangential to the request you are making and does not make the need clearer